# Killing subprocesses in a shell script

Tags: bash, signals

I would like to run processes with watchdogs that would restart them if they crashed. For that I have the following config file and process.sh:

```
$ cat process.sh 
#!/bin/bash

sleep $1;
exit -1

$ cat processes.cfg 
slow:./process.sh 5
fast:./process.sh 3
```

The following script reads processes.cfg and starts subprocesses using process.sh. I wrote that following

https://serverfault.com/questions/52976/simple-way-of-restarting-crashed-processes

```
#!/bin/bash

wtch () {

  until eval "$1" ; do
    echo "server '$2' crashed with exit code $? . respawning ..." >&2
    sleep 1
  done
}

cleanup () {

  echo killing subprocesses ...

  for i in "${!subproc[@]}"
  do
    echo killing ${subproc[$i]}
    kill -9 ${subproc[$i]}
  done

  echo exiting ...
  exit -1
}

declare -A subproc

cat processes.cfg | while IFS=: read name command
do
  echo "$command" "$name"
  wtch "$command" "$name" &
  subproc[$name]=$!
  echo $!
done

trap cleanup SIGINT

while true; do
  sleep 10;
done
```

Now, hitting ctrl-c does not kill the subprocesses as I would expect. For some reasons the `cleanup` function does not find anything in the subproc array.

Is this because the signal handler does not see the `subproc` array?

How can I make this work? I did this signal handler for the sake of testing, manually cleaning up the watchdog processes is tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `subproc` modification happens within a *subshell*, caused by [piping into a `while` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). Instead you can do `while […] done < processes.cfg` to keep the `while` loop within the same shell.